# SQL update with multiple criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, syntax-error

I know this is quite simple but I've been looking at this for awhile and can't seem to identify what the issue is. I want to update a row in a table using two criteria. When I use either criteria, the table updates fine but when I combine them, it doesn't work.

This is the query

```
$updatequery = "UPDATE query SET audio='$finalpath' WHERE content='$title' AND WHERE userid LIKE '%$regID%'";
```

An example of the reg id:

APA91bGHS59rrpM0sbX9PIYT3SzXs-W1yEtGa2xGMGJXi8O1vW2SrgN7koHDj2o6ZwKvkd3TxtzhktsiVtQNSYQRa4uNDF7Yy0VOf0BJfQOnJWMtN2WBQjmVDsuU-0GxmceNLd8SWqOM

An example of content : 
Where can I find a car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE content='$title' AND userid LIKE '%$regID%'
```

Where is needed only once

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use the `where` keyword once:

```
$updatequery = 
"UPDATE query SET audio='$finalpath' WHERE content='$title' AND userid LIKE '%$regID%'";
# "WHERE" removed here ------------------------------------^
```

Mandatory comment:
Using string manipulation like this leaves your code vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks. You should really consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong.

Try this:

```
 $updatequery = "UPDATE query SET audio='$finalpath' WHERE content='$title' AND userid LIKE '%$regID%'";
```

EDIT:
Where is needed only once.

Answer (score 1):

You can have only *one* `WHERE` clause, so this is a syntax error:

```
WHERE content='$title' AND WHERE userid LIKE '%$regID%'
```

Combine the logic in a single clause:

```
WHERE content='$title' AND userid LIKE '%$regID%'
```

The `WHERE` clause essentially works like conditionals in any other language.  You can build up as complex a tree of boolean conditions as you like, as long as the whole thing resolves down to a boolean then it's fine.